# Phaser 3 - Matter Physics - Unexpected "Jumping Bean" Behaviour

Tags: game-physics, phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm building a basic physics gaming using `Phaser 3` with the `MatterJS` physics engine.

(I've put an example of the game here for testing: [game demo](https://lazy-golf.netlify.app/))

All has been going well, but I'm currently seeing some strange behaviour when a `dynamic body`(*the  ball*) tries to rest on a flat `static body` (*the ground*). Instead of the ball losing all momentum / velocity and becoming still, it instead jumps around as if it is colliding with a moving object (the trail of the ball is shown in the screenshot provided).

This goes on forever as the ball keeps jumping in random directions and random heights.

I'm not sure what's causing this never-ending **ball** movement, but here's the code for the physics bodies:

Any ideas would be great!

**Note**: I'm using `Phaser.GameObjects.Container` for now as I made need to add other game objects to this container.

**Ball Game Object:**

```
export class HoleBall extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container {
  private ball: Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite;

  constructor(
    public scene: Phaser.Scene,
    public x: number,
    public y: number,
    private ballStartPosition: IPosition
  ) {
    super(scene, x, y);
    this.createPhysicsObjects();
  }

  private createPhysicsObjects(): void {
    const shapes = this.scene.cache.json.get(
      ECourseItems.COMMON_PHYSICS_SHAPES
    );

    this.ball = this.scene.matter.add
      .sprite(
        this.ballStartPosition.x,
        this.ballStartPosition.y,
        ECourseItems.COMMON_SPRITE_SHEET,
        ECourseItems.BALL,
        {
          shape: shapes.ball,
          label: ECourseItems.BALL,
        } as TMatterBody
      )
      .setSleepThreshold(settings.ball.sleepThreshold);
    this.ball.setDepth(2);
  }

  public getBall(): Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite {
    return this.ball;
  }
}
```

**Ground Game Object:**

```
export class HoleGround extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container {
  private ground: Phaser.Physics.Matter.Image;

  constructor(
    public scene: Phaser.Scene,
    public x: number,
    public y: number,
    private holePhysicsShapeKey: ECourseItems,
    private holeSpriteSheetKey: ECourseItems
  ) {
    super(scene, x, y);
    this.createPhysicsObjects();
  }

  private createPhysicsObjects(): void {
    const shapes = this.scene.cache.json.get(this.holePhysicsShapeKey);

    this.ground = this.scene.matter.add.image(
      0,
      0,
      this.holeSpriteSheetKey,
      ECourseItems.GROUND,
      {
        shape: shapes.ground,
        label: ECourseItems.GROUND,
      } as TMatterBody
    );

    this.ground.setStatic(true);

    this.scene.matter.alignBody(
      this.ground,
      this.scene.sys.game.canvas.width,
      this.scene.sys.game.canvas.height,
      Phaser.Display.Align.BOTTOM_CENTER
    );
  }

  public getGround(): Phaser.Physics.Matter.Image {
    return this.ground;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into JSON generated for the *ground* game object (generated by the [PhysicsEditor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor) app) - it seems it was generating multiple layers of physics bodies (unknown as to why, could be a bug with the app). But after manually removing the extra layers, the strange 'jumping' behaviour no longer happens.